# Dumping psql tables with specific prefixes

Tags: sql, administration, dump, postgresql

Im currently using the tool pg_dump to dump tables from my database. I would like to automate this process, however, i have not found a way to specify pg_dump to dump multiple databases that have the same prefix.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Examples from the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html):

> To dump all tables whose names start
>   with emp in the detroit schema, except
>   for the table named employee_log:
>
> $ pg_dump -t 'detroit.emp*' -T
>   detroit.employee_log mydb > db.sql
>
> To dump all schemas whose names start
>   with east or west and end in gsm,
>   excluding any schemas whose names
>   contain the word test:
>
> $ pg_dump -n 'east*gsm' -n 'west*gsm'
>   -N '*test*' mydb > db.sql
>
> The same, using regular expression
>   notation to consolidate the switches:
>
> $ pg_dump -n '(east|west)*gsm' -N
>   '*test*' mydb > db.sql
>
> To dump all database objects except
>   for tables whose names begin with ts_:
>
> $ pg_dump -T 'ts_*' mydb > db.sql

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what i needed. It was at the bottom of the manual - i have lost a little bit of my dignity.

Comment: tables != databases, so this is not a correct answer for the given question

Comment: childno͡.de probably means that OP has said: "i have not found a way to specify pg_dump to dump **multiple databases** that have the same prefix." So the question might be interpreted as one about databases, not tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter "-t" multiple times if you want to dump more than one table.

$ pg_dump -t table1 -t table2 mydb > dump.sql

> -t table
>   --table=table
>
> ```
> Dump only tables (or views or sequences) matching table. Multiple
> ```
>
> tables can be selected by writing
>   multiple -t switches.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that if I undstand what you said exactly. I advise you that you can edit a shell script to dump each database .

Comment: The database has many tables. Each subset of tables has a prefix. Foe example moscow_ paris_ newyork_. I would like to dump these substes with one command.